# Fill Color Selected Area in UIView upper Layer

Tags: ios, image, colors, paint, flood-fill

I am trying to develop paint type App for iPhone/iPad. I have done 70% but one functionality is taking time to complete it. I have added To Fill Selected Area with Selected Color functionality inside it. I did it but it is taking to much time or working too slow. Due to this functionality, whole App become freeze.
    Structure of Drawing View :-
    UIView(Parent View)
      -UIImageView(SubView1)-To keep image as a background
      -UIImageView(SubView2)-To draw color or draw line

```
In above structure, Parent view is work as a Canvas View and Subview1 is lowerview and Subview2 is upperview.

My approach :-
1)finding currnet point.
2)getting pixtel color.
3)get screen shot for whole screen.
4)get array for those pixtel who have a same pixtel color as select pixtel in current screen shot
5)now we use 4Q pixtel fill color for identifying pixtel who is connected with selected pixtel and making array for all those pixtel.
6)After getting the final array for the pixtel, we draw a pixtel with selected color.

Any one help.
I need a another implementation for Flood fill with a more smooth way functionality.
Pls provide me a Code sample.

Thanks in Advance.
```

Comment: I have seen a lot of implementations of the flood fill algorithm. Have you checked out the Apple docs and Core Graphics? Did you end up solving this or are you still searching?

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack based flood fill: http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2006/12/04/stack-based-flood-fill-algorithm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it worked a treat for me!

https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Very easy to implement too.